# Launch external app from java - and NOT have it tied to the VM

Tags: java, launch

There are times when my big Java app needs to launch an external program.
I can do that pretty easily with 
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("app name");

The problem is that the launched app seems to be tied to my Java process, as it gets terminated when my Java app then exits.  I want to leave the other app running.

Edit: Made a mistake with above description.
The launched app does NOT get terminated.

The problem is that after my original app exits, I can not start it again UNTIL the launched app terminates.  Original App (and launched app) are both Launch4J generated .exe's.

So, how can I keep the launched app from preventing a full exit from the original app?

(Oh, and just to throw another monkeywrench into it, the launched app uses a 32bit JVM, while the original app is running in a 64bit JVM.)

Answer (score 2):

While the shell command trick might work, I did find an easier way.

Desktop.getDesktop().open("app name");

Apparently that launches the app in a way that does NOT stay tied to the original program.

Comment: And this has the key advantage of not being system specific

Answer (score 0):

One way that should work is by running a shell command that starts your program as an independant process.

For instance on Linux (based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4006)):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/bin/sh", "-c", "nohup app_name &"});
```

An on Windows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "start app_name"});
```